# c++ how to get a value from a const parameter and assign it to a non-const variable

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am working on a cpp project in Unreal.
I know people like to use const and & everywhere to improve the efficiency,
but they make it difficult to pass values in the functions.

I create a derived class from UE4's projectile calculation component class
The parent class will call the compute acceleration function and pass a reference of the projectile's current velocity
I defined a separate UPROPERTY Velocity0 in the derived class(UNewActorComponent), I want to expose it to blueprint to report projectiles velocity, because the original velocity variable seems to be broken after I modify the acceleration function, it is printed as inf. 
I want to assign its value from the argument InVelocity  in ComputeAcceleration(const FVector & InVelocity, float DeltaTime)

This is the cpp file (reduced to minimum system)

```
FVector UNewActorComponent::ComputeAcceleration(const FVector & InVelocity, float DeltaTime) const
{
FVector Acceleration(FVector::ZeroVector);
Velocity0=InVelocity;  


 return Acceleration;
}
```

And this is the header

```
UCLASS(ClassGroup = Movement, meta = (BlueprintSpawnableComponent), ShowCategories = (Velocity))
class SHIPTEST_API UNewActorComponent : public UProjectileMovementComponent
{
 GENERATED_BODY()  
public:   
 UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = Projectile)
 FVector Velocity0;

protected:
 FVector ComputeAcceleration(const FVector& InVelocity, float DeltaTime) const override;

};
```

And, obviously, this is wrong, UE4's FVector does not have "=" operand,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRp6H.jpg)
but I can assign values to its element.
However, it still fails, it's caused by the const thing....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y20L.jpg)
So I then want to remove all the const key words to solve the problem, but still cannot fix it. Maybe because the base class has a const there, so I must add a const behind my function's argument list and ahead of override
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1u8G.png)
Then is it possible to do this value transfer?

Comment: I forgot to upload the image...I think assigning a const argument to a variable might need some other conversation

Comment: Don't know why you think that. You can prove it to yourself by (a) making `InVelocity` non-`const`, or (b) making a toy program that assigns the value of a `const int` to a non-`const` `int`.

Comment: The image and error seem to now be at odds with your code. It seems you've shown the result of erroneously attempting to fix this by making the target `const`, which is obviously impossible, and not shown in your code snippet. Please in future present a consistent and coherent [MCVE].

Comment: I just update it.  It seems to be a mix of the two possible problems..

Comment: The function parameter being `const` has no bearing on whether or not you can assign to the class member `Velocity0`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the method `ComputeAcceleration` itself is marked `const` and yet you are trying to modify a member variable within the method.

`FVector` definitely has an assignment operator, it would be quite useless without one.